# EXT4-fs boot error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

My dual boot ubuntu 18.04 LTS breaks down mid operation, I have to force shutdown and restart to get it to respond again.
The error in the prompt is `EXT4-fs error/ itable block` on the device id of the ssd partition containing LINUX filesystem.
AND
`system-journald[345]: failed to write items, ignoring read only file system.`
I am using the Samsung NVMe ssd with ASUS ROG g15, intel i7 10th gen .
I am aware that there have been similar queries. How ever I am hoping to get another solution that dosen't involve me replacing my ssd:(.

Comment: Have you checked the health of your hardware?  esp. disk (where the *fs* flips to RO to prevent dataloss due to errors - read your logs for exact details), but also PSU as bad power can cause perfect components to misbehave/fail...  Either way you should check your logs for clues then check your hardware (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools will be useful for checking disk health; GUI & TUI tools are available)

Comment: The hard drive has died or is close to it. error itable block and failed to write clear signs of that. As is that the drive is left in a read only state. Replacing the drive is the only solution. BTW overtime you do a force shut down you have the danger of damaging the file system.

Comment: Did you not also ask this question yesterday?

Comment: @guiverc, I had ran the smartctl however I did not find and errors and it passed the self-assesment test, I had also ran the CHKDSK on windows, I could not find any defects or badblocks. Here is the out put of my self assesment test :

Comment: https://snippet.host/rehqqc

Comment: Thank you for answering my query, also @David, I remember writing up a draft but not posting it.